# Unity - Connecting Beams for Puzzles

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Yo!

I'm working on a narrative focused game with some puzzles. I have a lot of game development experience but not a whole lot of coding experience so I need a bit of help.

I want to create a beam that the player can launch from an object by pressing a switch. That beam will then travel across the level to another object and activate an event, like opening a door when the object is "powered" by the beam.

I need it to work in the sense than sometimes there will be something blocking the beam, like a rock, and the player has to remove the rock so that the beam can connect.

How I think this works, is that I would create two points, and there would be a line created between them, and if the line detects a collision, the beam would stop from being drawn further, and if there's no collision, the beam will travel all the way and turn true the activation boolean that is required for the door or whatever to function.

I don't really even know where to begin with this, what do I need to do to make this happen and so on. I would appreciate any help greatly!

Comment: You need "Raycasting"
https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Physics.Raycast.html

Comment: Yeah, thanks. Managed to figure it out. It's working pretty well at this point. Consider the question answered.